# Schema.org organization json-ld does content need to be on page

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am looking to add JSON-LD data to our company's site and have been using the structured data testing tool to validate my schema data and it all seems ok.

My question though is whether the content in the JSON-LD schema needs to be human readable as part of the human readable page content as well?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? From my understanding you are asking whether the data added into the JSON-LD has to also be present on the page in plain text (human readable) also?

Comment: Have reworded slightly, for example, if we are adding a VAT number in the schema, does that information need to be available on the page when presented to a user as well.

Comment: "needs to be" according to what/whom?

Answer (score 1):

Google guidelines on the matter.

> At Google, our first priority is to help our users find relevant, engaging answers for their search queries. High-quality structured data must not create a misleading or deceptive experience for search users. **It should be an up-to-date and accurate reflection of the topic and content already found on the page**, such as text, images, and videos. For example:
>
> Markup should not be used to **hide content not visible to users in any form**, since it might create a misleading or deceptive search experience. For example, if the JSON-LD markup describes a performer, the HTML body should describe that same performer.
>
> [Source - Google, Quality guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#quality-guidelines)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the google formats and placement page. I notice this further down the page on the first link, might suggest that it does need to be on the page?

"Markup should not be used to hide content not visible to users in any form, since it might create a misleading or deceptive search experience."

Comment: @jonners99 I have edited my answer to incorporate that, good spot.